# Are Laravel 8 usernames safe to output?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the standard user authentication "package" in Laravel 8 to handle the authentication for my website.

I noticed that when I registered a test username, nearly every was accepted in the input field. Even Unicode control characters, such as a right-to-left mark, do not seem to get denied/stripped.

My question therefore is, are Laravel 8 usernames, as stored in the default authentication package, safe to output? I use standard Blade as the View rendering engine and use the following code to output the username:

```
{{ $user->name }}
```

I am therefore not worried about XSS attacks, since Blade escapes the username, but I am wondering if someone could break my site if they insert some weird control character in their username.

Comment: Blade's `{{ }}` echo statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent **XSS** attacks. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

I examined Laravel's protection `{{{...}}}` against XSS attack.It just uses the `htmlentities()` function.This protects you against XSS only if you use it properly means don't use it in certain HTML tags because it will result in XSS attack possibility. You must validate and sanitize data before inserting it into such places. I highly recommend read [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Base on [laravel 8 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data):

> Blade's `{{ }}` echo statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks.